# What is the initial defense sequence when there are unfilled spots in a gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

Say there is a level 7 gym, but with only 5 Pokemon in it. From highest ranked to lowest ranked, they are:

(1) Snorlax
(2) Dragonite
(3) Vaporeon
(4) Vileplume
(5) Jolteon
(6) ~ empty ~
(7) ~ empty ~

The current prestige is `23,000`.

Does an attacker fight Jolteon down to `20,000` and then start fighting Vileplume?
**or**
Does an attacker fight Jolteon down to `12,000` and then start fighting Vileplume?

Comment: the latter, assuming you mean jolteon leaves?

Comment: You fight all of them in a row anyway.

Comment: @Arperum True, but I was interested in, given unfilled positions, if the attacker would fight Jolteon, or Vileplume, for a longer period of time.

Comment: In that case is the answer exactly what you are after

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must reduce the prestige so that there in not enough space for Jolteon before you no longer have to face Jolteon.

It works just like if there were Pokemon in those slots. You will need to remove 3 levels before Jolteon leaves and Vileplume is the lowest defender.